I need to create a view for statement containing create table and drop tables
I need to create a view but an error occurs since statement after create view is IF statement.
Create View Test_Data AS

Checking if the Table exists to be dropped first
IF OBJECT_ID('Test_T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
Drop TABLE Test_T

Creating Table to fetch data from another table which spans the data into multiple rows and need to combine into same row different column.
I like to combine this process as part of the actual statement instead of creating a table, but unfortunately, I can not use the Group By on User_Pin column only.
CREATE TABLE Test_T (PerID nvarchar(50), PerF smallint, PerP smallint);
INSERT INTO Test_T Select 
    pb.user_pin,
    max(case when pb.user_type = '4'  then pb.user_type else 0 end),
        max(case when pb.user_type = '6'  then pb.user_type else 0 end)
    FROM    User_Data pb
GROUP BY  pb.user_pin;

SELECT DISTINCT people.pin AS [User ID],  people.last_name, people.name, dept.name, 
    STUFF ((SELECT ', ' + lvl.name FROM lvl WHERE people.pin = people_lvl.pin FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS [Level], 
(CASE Test_T.PerF WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [PerF], 
(CASE Test_T.PerP WHEN 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [PerP]

FROM    people 
        LEFT JOIN dept       ON people.dept_id = dept.id
        LEFT JOIN people_lvl ON people.lvl_id = people_lvl.id
        LEFT JOIN lvl        ON people_lvl.id = lvl.id
        LEFT JOIN Test_T     ON Test_T.PerID = people.pin 
ORDER BY
    people.pin
        

I have tried to move the IF statement before the Create View and an error occurs as well.
Unable to create view due to placement of the IF and also like possibility to remove create table and include in the same select distinct statement.

It's unclear where you started from but a view is a "virtual table" and created from a SELECT statement. It absolutely doesn't run arbitrary code or create or drop tables.

Add a tag for the dbms you're using. The above SQL is product specific in several ways.

You seems to have several, unrelated problems here. Ask separate questions instead, to get clearer answers.

A view is essentially a virtual table defined by a select statement. It cannot contain data manipulation code such as create or drop table statements. Maybe you can achieve what you want to do with a stored procedure instead, but the purpose is hard to read from your question

Thanks for explanation of the view function.
The goal is to join data from multiple tables where data in one of the table is spanning to multiple rows which I need to display in one row and different column as part of the join statement.
I was able to accomplish that without creating table / dropping table and using Group By, however group by expected all the columns to be listed in the group by which resulted inaccurate data.

@SQLNewby You’re welcome. I recommend you create a new question with your current query, the table schemas, sample data and the expected vs actual output. Ideally reduce the example as much as possible by removing tables and columns that are irrelevant to your grouping issue
